# Does updating innerHTML immediately update the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to add an element's HTML to a parent element and then immediately get the height of the parent element.

An example of what I want to do is:

```
parent.innerHTML += childHTML;
alert(parent.children[0].clientHeight);
```

This seems to work accurately in Chrome, but I know that JS is supposed to be single threaded, so in theory an implementation might have the DOM update after the thread has finished... but perhaps not?

Is it required to change the DOM immediately (at least in the way that I want it to), or does Chrome just use a convenient implementation?

Comment: As long as the content is not something that takes time to load (aka image without set size) you are fine.

Comment: It will update the DOM immediately. What web browsers do put off until your JavaScript is done running, is rendering that DOM, and alerting any MutationObserver.